# Switch positions for different labels in facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I've got a script like this:

```
ggplot(Plotdat_long, aes(x=Area, y=Value, fill=Area))
  facet_wrap(
    VariableName2~VariableName,
    scales = "free_y",
    switch = 'y',
    labeller = labeller(VariableName=custom_labels, VariableName2=y_axis_labels)
  )+
  ggtitle("Plot variables")
```

Where VariableName and VariableName2 are the exact same. However, I want to have labels for the titles of the variables, as well as the y axis values, which I why I've created 2 labels. However, they are positioned on top of each other. Is there a way to have custom_labels at the top, and y_axis_labels on the left? Thanks in advance!

I've tried changing the switch functions, which of course changes the position for both labels.

Comment: Maybe `facet_grid( ... , switch = "y")`? I don't think you can control the y_axis title in different facets, but you could manufacture that with different plots + the patchwork library.